# MySQL: Select values containing only one digit

Tags: mysql, regex

Let's say I have a column with emails:

```
test1@test.com
test2@test.com
test3test@tes.com
test123@test.com
test321@test.com
test23test.com
```

How can I select only those that contains only one digit?

Result should be:

```
test1@test.com
test2@test.com
test3test@tes.com
```

I tried:

`REGEXP '[[:digit:]]{1}'` and `REGEXP '[0-9]{1}'` but it shows all results that contain AT LEAST one digit

Answer (score 2):

try to use `^[^0-9]*[0-9]{1}[^0-9]*$`

Comment: Won't this match `test1test23@test.com` too? That has three digits.

Comment: No, as it looks only 1 digit followed by NON digit symbols

Comment: Yep, you're right. For some reason my brain saw `*` and thought "any character". Sorry about that.

Comment: Spasibo Ilya! :) Works wonderfully! Although, what if there are emails which start or end with 1 number?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify number of repetitions, it is one copy by default. 
Try something like

```
REGEXP '(^[0-9]+)([0-9])@.+'
```